# Clarification of conditional statements

Tags: logic

I've read a ton of posts on here explaining $P \rightarrow Q$ conditional statements, but I still don't quite get it. I want to present a few scenarios to maybe assist in my understanding of it.

**Question 1:**

If $1=1$, then $3=3$.

True/True: If $1=1$, then $3=3$. This is True

True/False: If $1=1$, then $3=4$. This is False

False/True: If $1=2$, then $3=3$. This is True

False/False: If $1=2$, then $3=4$. This is True

I don't really get the last two, of why (if $1=2$, then $3=3$) and (if $1=2$, then $3=4$) are both true.

**Question 2:**

Why is the nonsensical statement "if a square has three sides, then unicorns are real" a true statement? The truth table says if P is false and Q is either true or false, then the entire statement is true, but I don't understand why this is. (Where P is "a square has three sides" and Q is "unicorns are real").

**Question 3:**

Assume $x \in $ the set of all odd numbers. Prove that if $x$ is is even, then $x^2$ is even.

Proof: Because "$x$ is is even" is false, the whole sentence "if $x$ is is even, then $x^2$ is even" is true. QED.

Is this a valid proof then?

Comment: “I don’t get why…”-  Do you know the truth table for $\to$?

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku yes, but I don't understand the truth table for $\rightarrow$ (hence this question)

Comment: If $1 = 2$ then you can prove that any two numbers are equal: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion

Comment: “I don’t understand why this…” that’s the definition! If you are asking for the motivation behind the definition then that has been covered in plenty on this site.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku oh, I didn't know it was a definition. i thought there was some logical math leading up to the truth table responses which i was missing

Comment: You are far from alone in your confusion on this topic. Introductory logic textbooks often either give the "definition" of $A\to B$ as $\neg (A \land \neg B)$ (or equivalently $\neg A \lor B$), or they may present it as the "truth table"  all without any explanation beyond a few examples. And there is a good reason for that. To really understand why these "definitions" work, you need to first have a good grasp of the basic methods of proof. See the article at https://dcproof.wordpress.com/2017/12/28/if-pigs-could-fly/ for the details.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal to not be able to understand why conditional statements are defined to behave like this, because you are thinking about it purely in terms of propositional logic. In fact, conditional statements have very few applications if we are considering propositional logic alone. The real application of conditional statements rather happens in universal quantifications in first-order logic.

I am not sure if you are familiar with first-order logic, so I will be making a short introduction on universal quantification specifically. Consider the first-order statement below:

$\forall x\in\{1,8,3\}(x>0)$

The statement above is "translated" in english as: "For every element (x) of the set $\{1,8,3\}$, this element (x) is greater than 0." The same statement can also be "translated" (by definition) in propositional logic as follows;

$1>0 \land 8>0 \land 3>0$

By the way, as you can see the statement is true, but that's beside the point.

The statement inside of the round brackets in the first-order statement can be any statement from propositional logic that includes x. E.g. we can also say:

$\forall x\in\{1,8,3\}(x>2\lor x=1)$

This would be equivalent to

$(1>2 \lor 1=1) \land (8>2\lor8=1) \land (3>2\lor3=1)$

in propositional logic.

Now, say we want to define a first-order statement

$\forall x\in D(P(x)\implies Q(x))$

which we want to be translated as "For every x in D, whenever the statement $P(x)$ is true, Q(x) is also true". To have a better understanding, let's work with a specific example with a specific domain D and specific propositional statements. Consider the statement below;

$\forall x\in \{4,3,2,6\}(x \text{ is even}\implies x=2)$

In propositional logic:

$(4 \text{ is even}\implies4=2) \land (3 \text{ is even}\implies3=2) \land (2 \text{ is even}\implies2=2) \land (6 \text{ is even}\implies6=2)$

We immediately see a problem with the statement. 3 isn't even an even number in the first place, but the conditional $3 \text{ is even}\implies3=2$ must still return a true or false value, which might potentially influence the rest of the statement. If only there was a way to get rid of the the individual conditional involving 3 without affecting the rest of them...

But there IS a way! We know that $A \land \text{true}\iff A$, so if we define the conditional to be true when its first statement is false, then we can essentially "remove" it without affecting the other propositions! In our example:

$(4 \text{ is even}\implies4=2) \land (3 \text{ is even}\implies3=2) \land (2 \text{ is even}\implies2=2) \land (6 \text{ is even}\implies6=2)$

$(4 \text{ is even}\implies4=2) \land (\text{false}\implies3=2) \land (2 \text{ is even}\implies2=2) \land (6 \text{ is even}\implies6=2)$

$(4 \text{ is even}\implies4=2) \land \text{true} \land (2 \text{ is even}\implies2=2) \land (6 \text{ is even}\implies6=2)$

$(4 \text{ is even}\implies4=2) \land (2 \text{ is even}\implies2=2) \land (6 \text{ is even}\implies6=2)$

For the rest of the conditionals (i.e. whenever the first statement of the conditional is true), we define the conditional to be equivalent to its second statement.

$(\text{true}\implies4=2) \land (\text{true}\implies2=2) \land (\text{true}\implies6=2)$

$4=2\land2=2\land6=2$

(This statement is false, but that's beside the point)

We have ultimately reached our goal of defininf a binary opearator (the conditional) such that the statement

$\forall x\in D(P(x)\implies Q(x))$

gets translated as "For every x in D, whenever P(x), then also Q(x)". We did this by defining:

$(\text{false}\implies A)\iff\text{true}$

and

$(\text{true}\implies A)\iff A$

More specifically:

$(\text{false}\implies \text{false})\iff\text{true}$

$(\text{false}\implies \text{true})\iff\text{true}$

$(\text{true}\implies \text{false})\iff\text{false}$

$(\text{true}\implies \text{true})\iff\text{true}$

It just so happens that

$(A\implies B) \iff (\neg A \lor B)$

You can also check this on a truth table to see that it holds true.

Edit: It is also worth noting that by this definition, if you are faced with a first-order conditional whose first statement is always false, you are left with a conditional that is true by default, no matter what the second statement says. This seems to not make sense intuitively speaking, but it doesn't actually "break" anything anyway. Since the first statement is always false, you will never be able to "make use" of the implication anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For question 1, The statement P→Q can be considered a statement about a relation between P and Q.  It can be understood to mean that Q is not less true than P, or Q is at least as true as P. So, any statement Q (whether true or false) is least as true as a known falsehood P. A true statement Q is at least as true as any statement P (whether true or false).
It is thus a claim that it is logically valid, or truth preserving, to conclude Q given P. So, if we combine P (true premises) with P→Q (Valid reasoning), then we have a sound argument and may safely conclude Q.

In the case of question 2, the nonsense statement "if a square has three sides, then unicorns are real" is true because it is logically valid.  But it would be equally valid to claim that "if a square has three sides, then unicorns are not real". This illustrates that we can conclude anything we like (or nothing at all) with an unsound argument which combines a false premise with valid reasoning, so we aren't normally interested in that kind of technically valid argument. We could start with a true premise, but neither of our technically valid claims say anything about what happens if a square has four sides.

Likewise, for question 3. The argument is valid, but not sound, because it starts with a false premise.