# Why is the "implication" operation in mathematical logic called "implication"?

Tags: logic, soft-question, propositional-calculus, math-history

I can perfectly understand its definition in terms of other operations and its truth table. Still, I'm completely lost on why "implication" was chosen as the way to refer to it, when it is so disconnected from how we use the words "implication" and "imply" on a logical, day-to-day basis - in the same way we understand "sufficiency" to mean.

Yes, nothing was ever said about $A$ being false having anything to do with $B$ being either true or false when we say "A implies B" in a casual conversation, but the way $A\implies B$ is defined to be strictly true whenever $A$ is false creates a gap between how this word is used in mathematics and in verbal communication in a very striking way. Does this word encapsulate something I'm not seeing? Or is it just an unfortunate historical development, and I should just abstract away that this specific word was used?

Comment: “Implication” in everyday speech is ambiguous, like many other things that are definitely **not** strictly logical.

Comment: @DavidK But that's exactly why "implication" sounds like such a bad word choice in mathematics. In everyday speech it doesn't say anything about how $A$ entails $B$ when $A$ is false, yet in mathematics it categorically does. Is it the case that one should just ignore these differences and understand "implication" in maths and in everyday speech to mean two separate things that just happen to be referred to with the same word?

Comment: Suppose I say that if it is raining when I leave my house, I take an umbrella. And now suppose that this morning it was not raining when I left the house. Does that make my earlier statement false or meaningless? I think my original statement is still true. Moreover it remains true whether I took an umbrella or not (because I might make that decision based on a forecast). I think in this case the plain English matches mathematical implication fairly well—but only because of the particular things we’re dealing with. Use “if” in a different context and it means something different.

Comment: I think the problem is not that implication in math means something different than it does in English, but the implication in English doesn’t always mean the same thing.

Comment: @DavidK "I think my original statement is still true." I would also think so, and I don't see how this would conflict with everyday speech! The English "translation" of the  situation in your analogy would be, in my view, "To be raining at the time I leave my house implies I take my umbrella". The totality of this sentence would be colloquially understood to be true if both its statements were simultaneously true, and would be understood to be false if you ever left the house without an umbrella as it rains, irrespective of whether it is actually raining this day, tomorrow or some other day.

Comment: @DavidK You could still obviously leave the house with an umbrella if isn't raining. You might be safeguarding against rainfall later in the day. Or maybe you're more adventurous and choose to leave the umbrella home. Still, colloquially, these scenarios doesn't really impact in any way the first implication: "To be raining at the time I leave my house implies I take my umbrella." If we saw you leaving your house on a sunny day, we'd still have no idea how you would act on a rainy one, while the mathematical definition, as written in English, tells us that you would take your umbrella.

Comment: I've always thought "entail" is the word you would use when you want to ensure that people know you're talking about the "math implies" notion, and "implies" is used when the context is clear (e.g. in a mathematical discussion). At least, this was my experience in philosophy courses I took when in college, where people are especially careful with language usage.

Comment: "Implication" is an utterly natural terminology. "$A\implies B$" means that $A$ implies $B$ (in other words that we can conclude $B$ from $A$). It does not say anything about the case if $A$ is false, but this is not critical.

Comment: What distinguishes math from the daily life usage is that everything can be derived from a false statement. We would hardly accept this in real life : "If Paris is the capital of Russia , then Isaac Newton is still alive" would barely be considered to be a valid implication in real life.

Comment: The meaning of $A$ being entangled to $B$ fits. The meaning of $B$ being said implicitly or between then lines when $A$ is said also fits.

Comment: When you are hanging out with a group of friends, do you have an operation defined? Who's the neutral element? Who's your inverse? What about rings, then? When you give a ring as gift, what's the multiplication defined on it? What about when you see a field of wheat or corn?

Comment: I will comment on the "terminology" aspect (and NOT on the truth table definition): the founding father of modern mathematical logic: G.Frege (*Begriffsschrift*, 1879) that used for the modern symbolic version of "if..., then..." the name *conditional* [original: *bedingtheit*]. It seems that the unfortunate choice of "material implication" is due to B.Russell, *The Theory of Implication* (1906): "When a proposition q is a consequence of a proposition p, we say that p *implies* q. [...] 1/2

Comment: Hence, "p implies q" will be a relation which holds between any two entities p and q unless p is true and q is not true, i. e. whenever either p is not true or q is true." 2/2

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA: To correct my previous comment in light of your mention of "material implication", it's MATERIAL IMPLICATION that I recall philosophers often using. Although they also often said entails, material implication is actually what I was thinking of earlier.

Comment: The confusion between today's $\to$ and $\vdash$ has been reinforced by the use of material implication in the *magnus opus* of 1910-13: *Principia Mathematica*. Further confusion arise when C.I.Lewis, correctly understanding the need of a clear distinction between the conditional connective and the relation of logical consequence, introduced a new "connective $⥽$ called [strict implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_conditional) for the second one (defined as $\Box (p\rightarrow q)$).

Answer (score 5):

There actually is colloquial language corresponding to "false implies anything," sort of, e.g. sayings like "that'll happen [when pigs fly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_pigs_fly)" or "[when Hell freezes over](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=when%20hell%20freezes%20over)."

Most of the time we don't bother stating "false implies anything" implications in colloquial language because, by assumption, their antecedents are impossible, so most of the time these statements aren't very *useful*. However, in mathematics we do things like [proof by contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction) where we assume a statement precisely to show that it is false by deriving other obviously false conclusions from it. So in mathematics we actually do need to consider the effects of assuming things that are impossible.

Anyway, as far as I'm concerned the primary justification for talking about material implication is [modus ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens): $p \to q$ is the statement such that, given $p$ and $p \to q$, we can deduce $q$. And the material implication has this property. And this is what we need to write proofs, *including* proofs by contradiction. So we use that.

There's a different and more psychological or perhaps philosophical question of how to really capture the nuances of how implication gets used in colloquial language. One might argue that in colloquial language "$P$ implies $Q$" has something to do with considering possible counterfactual worlds in which $P$ is true, and examining whether $Q$ is true in those worlds; thinking about this more leads to [modal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_logic), [strict implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_conditional), and [Kripke semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_semantics). I don't know that these formalisms really say anything about the nuances of what humans would consider "plausible" vs. "implausible" counterfactual worlds, though.

The SEP article on [logical consequence](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logical-consequence/) might also be a relevant read.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that implication is hard to make sense of in a propositional context; the way we talk about implication seems to be talking about variable truth values rather than fixed ones. Really, I think that when we talk about implication, there’s implicitly a universal quantifier. I.e. most implications we talk about are of the form $\forall x \;P(x)\to Q(x)$. Now, to check the truth value of a universal quantifier, we check that the inner proposition is true for each $x$. In this framing, I think the truth table for implication makes sense: for each instance we’re checking, we don’t care if $P(x)$ is false, so in this case we should set the truth value to true, because that will have no bearing on the truth if the universal quantifier. The only thing that can make the whole thing false is if there is an $x$ so that $P(x)$ is true and $Q(x)$ is false, so that is the only case in which we need to define implication to be false.

Comment: This is the best explanation. You won't be missing out on ANYTHING if you never use implication when working with propositional logic. It was defined specifically with first-order logic in mind.

Answer (score 0):

> [T]he way $A\implies B$ is defined to be strictly true whenever $A$ is
> false creates a gap between how this word is used in mathematics and
> in verbal communication in a very striking way.

If proposition $A$ is false, then the implication $A \implies B$ is true regardless of the truth value of $B$. This principle of *vacuous truth* is rarely if ever used in our daily discourse because we are rarely concerned about the implications of propositions that are known to be false, but it is a legitimate method of proof in mathematics.

We can verify that $\neg A \implies (A \implies B)$ in a truth table:

[image]

Source: https://www.erpelstolz.at/gateway/TruthTable.html

We can also formally prove it from "first principles" using a form of natural deduction (screenshot from a freeware proof checker):

[image]

Comment: The usefulness of being able to operate with the implications of propositions that are known to be false certainly goes unquestioned. I'm not arguing against the sanity in this method, but specifically about how the English word "implication" seems like bad word choice to reflect what is being expressed with this operation. "This principle of vacuous truth is rarely if ever used in our daily discourse". This is precisely why it seems like bad word choice: the same word expressing two partly unrelated concepts.

Comment: @jvf You might think of logical implication as a tool with multiple uses. Full use of these features (including vacuous truth) is rarely made outside of mathematical proofs.

Comment: "You might think of logical implication as a tool with multiple uses. Full use of these features (including vacuous truth) is rarely made outside of mathematical proofs." Absolutely! Like I said, I'm not questioning the reasoning behind the definition of an operation that has this truth table and the various uses it has, I'm questioning the reasonableness in naming this operation "implication", when this word in everyday speech has such a close but simultaneously distant meaning. I'm asking the reason it takes on this name.

Comment: This operation could potentially have another name tailored for mathematics. I've never, ever, seen the word "diffeomorphism" used outside of a mathematical context, for example.

Comment: @jvf Not so distant, really. The technical meaning subsumes the "everyday" meaning.

Comment: @jvf It might seem a bit odd, but  no errors would result in real-life if we used the principle of vacuous truth in our reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an answer to a very similiar question written just a few hours before yours. It should be able to answer your question as well, just keep in mind that in my answer I was refering to "implication" as "conditional", because that is how the question was phrased.

Here is the link: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4534223/858891

Feel free to ask follow-up questions in the comments!

Answer (score 0):

As is has developed, formal mathematical logic is based on an abstract simplification of our natural process of reasoning. It classifies all statements as either true or false. This procrustean approach works well in mathematics, but it doesn't work so well in the natural world. There are instances where we may agree that something must be either true or false, but cannot tell which is the case, and there are others where distinctions are matters of degree. Furthermore, on a daily basis we deal with doubtful conditionals such as "If I do x, then y will happen",and our methods for dealing with them are informal and intuitive. We have not yet developed satisfactory formal methods for dealing with such cases, although outside mathematics we deal with the uncertain and unknown all the time. Even our formal methods of dealing with modal logic, the logic of the necessary, possible, and contingent, which is as old as Aristotle, are not entirely satisfactory.

For instance, in mathematics, we are accustomed to dealing with well-defined sets, in which we can tell whether a given object is or is not an element of a set, and how many there are, or at least whether there is a countable or an uncountable infinity of them. The sets of every day life are often fuzzier. We may not know how many objects are in a set, or whether a given object is or is not an element of a set.

The material conditional in formal logic does correspond to the notion of implication as used in natural language, although the limitations of classical logic mean that the correspondence is imperfect. In colloquial discourse we are normally not interested in technically valid but unsound arguments from false premises, although formal logic must account for these as well as the more usual techniques of sound deduction from true premises and valid inference.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to understand the material conditional P->Q is just to say “if you assume P, then Q follows.” This might be true because other assumptions are involved. The way we usually think of implication is more akin to *strict* implication, which says “if you assume P, then from no other assumptions but the axioms and rules of your proof system, Q follows.” This version of implication has used the fishhook symbol P⥽Q, but it’s more common to see the modal logic version □(P->Q). The advantage to the modal version is that it’s defined in terms of the material conditional, but has modal machinery in order to preserve the difference between the material conditional and strict implication.